# AngularJS- how to change value of backend Python variable from AngularJS frontend function?

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, variables, web-frontend

I am currently working on a web based application, for which the back end has been developed using Django & Python, and the front end has been developed using AngularJS.

There is a form on one of the pages in the front end, which the user can use to export data that has been recorded & stored in the back end to a spreadsheet.

All of the data recorded in the back end is 'time sensitive', and at present, there is only one time zone set in the back end (UTC). I want to 'create' settings for adding multiple new time zones, so that the data recorded can be exported in different time zones.

The time zone is set in project/apps/appAbc/abc/settings.py with:

```
class Production(Settings):
    ...
    TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
    ...
```

The 'Export' form has a number of fields (preset, type of data, sort data by quantity/ period, file type to export to), and I have just added a 'Timezone' drop down to it:

```
<section class="panel panel-brand export-page panel-no-border-radius">
<div class="panel-body panel-body-fixed-md">
    ...
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <label data-i18n="Timezone:" class="col-sm-3"></label>
        <div ul-timezone-picker callback="selectTimezone" class="col-sm-9" default-label={{presetTimezone}} btn-class="btn-xs btn-default"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="row" ul-scroll-to-me="scrollToFtype">
        <label data-i18n="File type:" class="col-sm-3"></label>
        <div ul-options-menu class="col-sm-9" options="ftypeOptions"
             callback="selectFType" warning="{{ftypeWarning}}"
             btn-class="btn-xs btn-default" default-idx="0" default-label="{{presetFtype}}"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divider divider-lg"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-brand" ng-hide="!btnDisabled" ng-click="setDownloadUrl(true)">
                <i class="ti-export"></i>
                <span data-i18n="Export"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-brand" role="button" target="_blank" href="{{downloadURL}}" ng-hide="btnDisabled">
                <i class="ti-export"></i>
                <span data-i18n="Export"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in Pages/directive.js, I have added multiple timezones to the `ulTimezonePicker` controller:

```
.directive('ulTimezonePicker', function() {
    return {
        ...
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.options = [{label: 'UTC', value: 0},
            // Add in other timezones
            {label: 'GMT', value: 1},
            {label: 'BST', value: 2},
        ];
        ...
    ...
})
```

The `selectTimezone()` function that is called by the `ul-timezone-picker` field on the form is defined in project/libs/front/app/scripts/app/pages/exportCtrl.js with:

```
angular.module('app.pages').controller('ExportCtrl',
    function(...) {
        ...
        $scope.selectTimezone = function(option){
            if(option) {
                $scope.timezone = option;
                if(option.label != $scope.presetTimezone) {
                    $scope.presetTimezone = undefined;
                }
            }
        };
    ...
    }
}
```

So, my question is, how do I get the `selectTimezone()` function to actually change the value of the `TIME_ZONE` variable defined in settings.py?

I tried declaring an instance of the variable within the function with:

```
Production.TIME_ZONE = $scope.timezone;
```

But when I do this, and view the page that has the form on it in a browser, the browser console gives me an error stating:

> ReferenceError: Production is not defined

How do I actually get hold of that Python class from within the AngularJS function, to change the value of one of its variables?

Comment: What about learning about the HTTP protocol and client-side code vs server-side code ? Might be a good idea if you're supposed to do anything web-related...

Comment: Oh and yes: Django settings are NOT to be messed with - not even from django code itself - so even if you _could_ do what you describe this just wouldn't work.

Comment: The Django settings file for this project has clearly been modified- as there are some custom permissions that have been written in this file (done before I started working on this project).

Comment: Sorry my point wasn't clear : django settings are to be considered read-only during the process execution. Of course you have to edit the settings files every now and then - those are settings, that's what they are for - but not during process execution.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't talk to Python classes from AngularJS. Your Python app and your Angular app are two separate programs that don't even run on the same computer.

The challenge here is to invent a "language" that these two programs can communicate. There's a good amount of ways you could design such a language, HTTP is a great default pick.

Your back-end is using Django and Django is quite good at understanding and responding to HTTP requests. Take a day or two to go over the Django tutorial, figure out how to make a Django app, then think what HTTP endpoint your app needs to be able to handle. Add it to your backend, test it a little, then move over to the Angular app.

> Careful though - Django apps normally don't rely on global state stored in a class like `class Production` and instead store the state in databases.

Once you have the backend in place, use Angular's [`$http` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) to send requests to the address you just added.

I'm a bit vague (sorry) but I'm assuming here that you're new to Django at the moment, and the tutorial will be more helpful than I could possibly be. Good luck!

Comment: the 'state' in question is django's settings and they are indeed not supposed to be ever mutated during execution (Django's doc is quite clear about it), so this won't solve the OP's problem.